# How to map '/' in a url-map?

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In `Networking` -> `Load Balancin`g -> `Host and path rules`,  I have defined a url map to map '/', '/blog/', 'features/' and '/pricing/' to a wordpress backend/

[image]

However when I add a configuration test for '/', I got this error message:

[image]

My intention is to have a couple well-known url to map to a wordpress back end and the rest gets directed to another backend service.

Why '/' in the rule above does not map 'www.examples.com/' to the wordpress services?

**EDIT**

1) As requested by Grisha Levit in the comment

```
>>  gcloud compute backend-services describe backend-service-url-mapper
affinityCookieTtlSec: 0
backends:
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 1.0
  description: ''
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/zones/us-central1-c/instanceGroups/instance-group-forward-to-gae
  maxUtilization: 0.8
connectionDraining:
  drainingTimeoutSec: 300
creationTimestamp: '2017-01-16T18:18:24.815-08:00'
description: ''
enableCDN: false
fingerprint: jx1UyRlAaXY=
healthChecks:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/httpHealthChecks/health-check-wordpress
id: '5709193638199738399'
kind: compute#backendService
loadBalancingScheme: EXTERNAL
name: backend-service-url-mapper
port: 80
portName: http
protocol: HTTP
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/backendServices/backend-service-url-mapper
sessionAffinity: NONE
timeoutSec: 30
```

It is basically a bunch of nginx servers.

2) Here is the full picture of all the rules:

[image]

Comment: What is `backend-service-url-mapper`? Can you post the config for that?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: You are matching `/*` in the second rule so it's not clear what the problem is. It sounds like removing the second rule will make this work like you want.

Comment: The 2nd rule is created by gcloud command as far as I can tell https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-discussion/JoxIFRaT0Us/ylnx3FHhDQAJ

Answer (score 2):

A setup like this one worked for me using two backends (NGINX and Apache)
[image]

The HTTP requests got redirected as follow:

http://test.mydomain.com/           to NGINX

http://test.mydomain.com/blog       to NGINX

http://test.mydomain.com/pricing    to NGINX

http://test.mydomain.com/anything   to Apache

It might take a couple of minutes for Health checks to work and the Load Balancer to update new settings. Referenced document can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/content-based-example).